# C# anonymous object with properties from dictionary

Tags: c#, object, dictionary

I'm trying to convert an dictionary to an anonymous type with one property for every Key.

I tried google it but all I could find was how to convert a anonymous object to a dictionary.

My dictionary looks something like this:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    {"Id", "1"},
    {"Title", "My title"},
    {"Description", "Blah blah blah"},
};
```

And i would like to return a anonymous object that looks like this.

```
var o = new 
{
    Id = "1",
    Title = "My title",
    Description = "Blah blah blah"
};
```

So I would like it to loop thru every keyValuePair in the dictionary and create a property in the object for every key.

I don't know where to begin.

Please help.

Comment: What are you using the anonymous object for?  C# isn't javascript.

Comment: I'm not sure this is possible in this way, as the object you've presented here is generated into a class at compile time, so you couldn't create the properties at runtime.

Comment: An anonymous type isn't a dynamic type: take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/391529/anonymous-type-vs-dynamic-type

Comment: Even if this was possible callers wouldn't be able to use that object because the members of that object would be runtime determined. C# is statically taped.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can't, basically. Anonymous types are created by the compiler, so they exist in your assembly with all the property names baked into them. (The property *types* aren't a problem in this case - as an implementation detail, the compiler creates a generic type and then creates an instance of that using appropriate type arguments.)

You're asking for a type with properties which are determined at *execution* time - which just doesn't fit with how anonymous types work. You'd have to basically compile code using it at execution time - which would then be a pain as it would be in a different assembly, and anonymous types are internal...

Perhaps you should use [`ExpandoObject`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject) instead? Then anything using `dynamic` will be able to access the properties as normal.

Comment: He could still dynamically create a new type through reflection. I don't *say* it would be useful or intelligent... It seems a XY problem

Comment: @xanatos He can't dynamically create a new anonymous type though. That has to be generated by the compiler at compile time. Yes smells like XY problem.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel The concept of "anonymous" is simply "you don't write it in C# code, and the compiler generates it with a funny name and some attributes"... He can surely create a new type, give it a funny name and some attributes... Technically it won't be an anonymous type, but the difference is minimal

Comment: @xanatos It is not that I disagree. You're right indeed. My point is in C# terms anonymous type is something which the compiler creates not us.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel So he should use the `CodeDomProvider`/`CSharpCodeProvider`, so even the form would be correct :)

Comment: Whoever got away with naming that `ExpandoObject` instead of something sensible like `ExpandableObject` should get a promotion lol

Answer (score 23):

Now, at least once a month someone asks how to create an anonymous type at runtime... Here is the response:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Reflection.Emit;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;

/// <summary>
/// The code generated should be nearly equal to the one generated by
/// csc 12.0.31101.0 when compiling with /optimize+ /debug-. The main
/// difference is in the GetHashCode() (the base init_hash used is 
/// compiler-dependant) and in the maxstack of the generated methods.
/// Note that Roslyn (at least the one present at 
/// tryroslyn.azurewebsites.net) generates different code for anonymous
/// types.
/// </summary>
public static class AnonymousType
{
    private static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, Type> GeneratedTypes = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, Type>();

    private static readonly AssemblyBuilder AssemblyBuilder;
    private static readonly ModuleBuilder ModuleBuilder;
    private static readonly string FileName;

    // Some objects we cache
    private static readonly CustomAttributeBuilder CompilerGeneratedAttributeBuilder = new CustomAttributeBuilder(typeof(CompilerGeneratedAttribute).GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes), new object[0]);
    private static readonly CustomAttributeBuilder DebuggerBrowsableAttributeBuilder = new CustomAttributeBuilder(typeof(DebuggerBrowsableAttribute).GetConstructor(new[] { typeof(DebuggerBrowsableState) }), new object[] { DebuggerBrowsableState.Never });
    private static readonly CustomAttributeBuilder DebuggerHiddenAttributeBuilder = new CustomAttributeBuilder(typeof(DebuggerHiddenAttribute).GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes), new object[0]);

    private static readonly ConstructorInfo ObjectCtor = typeof(object).GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes);
    private static readonly MethodInfo ObjectToString = typeof(object).GetMethod("ToString", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public, null, Type.EmptyTypes, null);

    private static readonly ConstructorInfo StringBuilderCtor = typeof(StringBuilder).GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes);
    private static readonly MethodInfo StringBuilderAppendString = typeof(StringBuilder).GetMethod("Append", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public, null, new[] { typeof(string) }, null);
    private static readonly MethodInfo StringBuilderAppendObject = typeof(StringBuilder).GetMethod("Append", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public, null, new[] { typeof(object) }, null);

    private static readonly Type EqualityComparer = typeof(EqualityComparer<>);
    private static readonly Type EqualityComparerGenericArgument = EqualityComparer.GetGenericArguments()[0];
    private static readonly MethodInfo EqualityComparerDefault = EqualityComparer.GetMethod("get_Default", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public, null, Type.EmptyTypes, null);
    private static readonly MethodInfo EqualityComparerEquals = EqualityComparer.GetMethod("Equals", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public, null, new[] { EqualityComparerGenericArgument, EqualityComparerGenericArgument }, null);
    private static readonly MethodInfo EqualityComparerGetHashCode = EqualityComparer.GetMethod("GetHashCode", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public, null, new[] { EqualityComparerGenericArgument }, null);

    private static int Index = -1;

    static AnonymousType()
    {
        var assemblyName = new AssemblyName("AnonymousTypes");

        FileName = assemblyName.Name + ".dll";

        AssemblyBuilder = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly(assemblyName, AssemblyBuilderAccess.RunAndSave);
        ModuleBuilder = AssemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicModule("AnonymousTypes", FileName);
    }

    public static void Dump()
    {
        AssemblyBuilder.Save(FileName);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="types"></param>
    /// <param name="names"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static Type CreateType(Type[] types, string[] names)
    {
        if (types == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("types");
        }

        if (names == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("names");
        }

        if (types.Length != names.Length)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("names");
        }

        // Anonymous classes are generics based. The generic classes
        // are distinguished by number of parameters and name of 
        // parameters. The specific types of the parameters are the 
        // generic arguments. We recreate this by creating a fullName
        // composed of all the property names, separated by a "|"
        string fullName = string.Join("|", names.Select(x => Escape(x)));

        Type type;

        if (!GeneratedTypes.TryGetValue(fullName, out type))
        {
            // We create only a single class at a time, through this lock
            // Note that this is a variant of the double-checked locking.
            // It is safe because we are using a thread safe class.
            lock (GeneratedTypes)
            {
                if (!GeneratedTypes.TryGetValue(fullName, out type))
                {
                    int index = Interlocked.Increment(ref Index);

                    string name = names.Length != 0 ? string.Format("<>f__AnonymousType{0}`{1}", index, names.Length) : string.Format("<>f__AnonymousType{0}", index);
                    TypeBuilder tb = ModuleBuilder.DefineType(name, TypeAttributes.AnsiClass | TypeAttributes.Class | TypeAttributes.AutoLayout | TypeAttributes.NotPublic | TypeAttributes.Sealed | TypeAttributes.BeforeFieldInit);
                    tb.SetCustomAttribute(CompilerGeneratedAttributeBuilder);

                    GenericTypeParameterBuilder[] generics = null;

                    if (names.Length != 0)
                    {
                        string[] genericNames = Array.ConvertAll(names, x => string.Format("<{0}>j__TPar", x));
                        generics = tb.DefineGenericParameters(genericNames);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        generics = new GenericTypeParameterBuilder[0];
                    }

                    // .ctor
                    ConstructorBuilder constructor = tb.DefineConstructor(MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.HideBySig, CallingConventions.HasThis, generics);
                    constructor.SetCustomAttribute(DebuggerHiddenAttributeBuilder);
                    ILGenerator ilgeneratorConstructor = constructor.GetILGenerator();
                    ilgeneratorConstructor.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
                    ilgeneratorConstructor.Emit(OpCodes.Call, ObjectCtor);

                    var fields = new FieldBuilder[names.Length];

                    // There are two for cycles because we want to have
                    // all the getter methods before all the other 
                    // methods
                    for (int i = 0; i < names.Length; i++)
                    {
                        // field
                        fields[i] = tb.DefineField(string.Format("<{0}>i__Field", names[i]), generics[i], FieldAttributes.Private | FieldAttributes.InitOnly);
                        fields[i].SetCustomAttribute(DebuggerBrowsableAttributeBuilder);

                        // .ctor
                        constructor.DefineParameter(i + 1, ParameterAttributes.None, names[i]);
                        ilgeneratorConstructor.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);

                        if (i == 0)
                        {
                            ilgeneratorConstructor.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);
                        }
                        else if (i == 1)
                        {
                            ilgeneratorConstructor.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_2);
                        }
                        else if (i == 2)
                        {
                            ilgeneratorConstructor.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_3);
                        }
                        else if (i < 255)
                        {
                            ilgeneratorConstructor.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_S, (byte)(i + 1));
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            // Ldarg uses a ushort, but the Emit only
                            // accepts short, so we use a unchecked(...),
                            // cast to short and let the CLR interpret it
                            // as ushort
                            ilgeneratorConstructor.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg, unchecked((short)(i + 1)));
                        }

                        ilgeneratorConstructor.Emit(OpCodes.Stfld, fields[i]);

                        // getter
                        MethodBuilder getter = tb.DefineMethod(string.Format("get_{0}", names[i]), MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.HideBySig | MethodAttributes.SpecialName, CallingConventions.HasThis, generics[i], Type.EmptyTypes);
                        ILGenerator ilgeneratorGetter = getter.GetILGenerator();
                        ilgeneratorGetter.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
                        ilgeneratorGetter.Emit(OpCodes.Ldfld, fields[i]);
                        ilgeneratorGetter.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

                        PropertyBuilder property = tb.DefineProperty(names[i], PropertyAttributes.None, CallingConventions.HasThis, generics[i], Type.EmptyTypes);
                        property.SetGetMethod(getter);
                    }

                    // ToString()
                    MethodBuilder toString = tb.DefineMethod("ToString", MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.Virtual | MethodAttributes.HideBySig, CallingConventions.HasThis, typeof(string), Type.EmptyTypes);
                    toString.SetCustomAttribute(DebuggerHiddenAttributeBuilder);
                    ILGenerator ilgeneratorToString = toString.GetILGenerator();

                    ilgeneratorToString.DeclareLocal(typeof(StringBuilder));

                    ilgeneratorToString.Emit(OpCodes.Newobj, StringBuilderCtor);
                    ilgeneratorToString.Emit(OpCodes.Stloc_0);

                    // Equals
                    MethodBuilder equals = tb.DefineMethod("Equals", MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.Virtual | MethodAttributes.HideBySig, CallingConventions.HasThis, typeof(bool), new[] { typeof(object) });
                    equals.SetCustomAttribute(DebuggerHiddenAttributeBuilder);
                    equals.DefineParameter(1, ParameterAttributes.None, "value");
                    ILGenerator ilgeneratorEquals = equals.GetILGenerator();
                    ilgeneratorEquals.DeclareLocal(tb);

                    ilgeneratorEquals.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);
                    ilgeneratorEquals.Emit(OpCodes.Isinst, tb);
                    ilgeneratorEquals.Emit(OpCodes.Stloc_0);
                    ilgeneratorEquals.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc_0);

                    Label equalsLabel = ilgeneratorEquals.DefineLabel();

                    // GetHashCode()
                    MethodBuilder getHashCode = tb.DefineMethod("GetHashCode", MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.Virtual | MethodAttributes.HideBySig, CallingConventions.HasThis, typeof(int), Type.EmptyTypes);
                    getHashCode.SetCustomAttribute(DebuggerHiddenAttributeBuilder);
                    ILGenerator ilgeneratorGetHashCode = getHashCode.GetILGenerator();
                    ilgeneratorGetHashCode.DeclareLocal(typeof(int));

                    if (names.Length == 0)
                    {
                        ilgeneratorGetHashCode.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4_0);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // As done by Roslyn
                        // Note that initHash can vary, because
                        // string.GetHashCode() isn't "stable" for 
                        // different compilation of the code
                        int initHash = 0;

                        for (int i = 0; i < names.Length; i++)
                        {
                            initHash = unchecked(initHash * (-1521134295) + fields[i].Name.GetHashCode());
                        }

                        // Note that the CSC seems to generate a 
                        // different seed for every anonymous class
                        ilgeneratorGetHashCode.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4, initHash);
                    }

                    for (int i = 0; i < names.Length; i++)
                    {
                        // Equals()
                        Type equalityComparerT = EqualityComparer.MakeGenericType(generics[i]);
                        MethodInfo equalityComparerTDefault = TypeBuilder.GetMethod(equalityComparerT, EqualityComparerDefault);
                        MethodInfo equalityComparerTEquals = TypeBuilder.GetMethod(equalityComparerT, EqualityComparerEquals);

                        ilgeneratorEquals.Emit(OpCodes.Brfalse_S, equalsLabel);
                        ilgeneratorEquals.Emit(OpCodes.Call, equalityComparerTDefault);
                        ilgeneratorEquals.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
                        ilgeneratorEquals.Emit(OpCodes.Ldfld, fields[i]);
                        ilgeneratorEquals.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc_0);
                        ilgeneratorEquals.Emit(OpCodes.Ldfld, fields[i]);
                        ilgeneratorEquals.Emit(OpCodes.Callvirt, equalityComparerTEquals);

                        // GetHashCode();
                        MethodInfo EqualityComparerTGetHashCode = TypeBuilder.GetMethod(equalityComparerT, EqualityComparerGetHashCode);

                        ilgeneratorGetHashCode.Emit(OpCodes.Stloc_0);
                        ilgeneratorGetHashCode.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4, -1521134295);
                        ilgeneratorGetHashCode.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc_0);
                        ilgeneratorGetHashCode.Emit(OpCodes.Mul);
                        ilgeneratorGetHashCode.Emit(OpCodes.Call, equalityComparerTDefault);
                        ilgeneratorGetHashCode.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
                        ilgeneratorGetHashCode.Emit(OpCodes.Ldfld, fields[i]);
                        ilgeneratorGetHashCode.Emit(OpCodes.Callvirt, EqualityComparerTGetHashCode);
                        ilgeneratorGetHashCode.Emit(OpCodes.Add);

                        // ToString()
                        ilgeneratorToString.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc_0);
                        ilgeneratorToString.Emit(OpCodes.Ldstr, i == 0 ? string.Format("{{ {0} = ", names[i]) : string.Format(", {0} = ", names[i]));
                        ilgeneratorToString.Emit(OpCodes.Callvirt, StringBuilderAppendString);
                        ilgeneratorToString.Emit(OpCodes.Pop);
                        ilgeneratorToString.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc_0);
                        ilgeneratorToString.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
                        ilgeneratorToString.Emit(OpCodes.Ldfld, fields[i]);
                        ilgeneratorToString.Emit(OpCodes.Box, generics[i]);
                        ilgeneratorToString.Emit(OpCodes.Callvirt, StringBuilderAppendObject);
                        ilgeneratorToString.Emit(OpCodes.Pop);
                    }

                    // .ctor
                    ilgeneratorConstructor.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

                    // Equals()
                    if (names.Length == 0)
                    {
                        ilgeneratorEquals.Emit(OpCodes.Ldnull);
                        ilgeneratorEquals.Emit(OpCodes.Ceq);
                        ilgeneratorEquals.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4_0);
                        ilgeneratorEquals.Emit(OpCodes.Ceq);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ilgeneratorEquals.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
                        ilgeneratorEquals.MarkLabel(equalsLabel);
                        ilgeneratorEquals.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4_0);
                    }

                    ilgeneratorEquals.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

                    // GetHashCode()
                    ilgeneratorGetHashCode.Emit(OpCodes.Stloc_0);
                    ilgeneratorGetHashCode.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc_0);
                    ilgeneratorGetHashCode.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

                    // ToString()
                    ilgeneratorToString.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc_0);
                    ilgeneratorToString.Emit(OpCodes.Ldstr, names.Length == 0 ? "{ }" : " }");
                    ilgeneratorToString.Emit(OpCodes.Callvirt, StringBuilderAppendString);
                    ilgeneratorToString.Emit(OpCodes.Pop);
                    ilgeneratorToString.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc_0);
                    ilgeneratorToString.Emit(OpCodes.Callvirt, ObjectToString);
                    ilgeneratorToString.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

                    type = tb.CreateType();

                    type = GeneratedTypes.GetOrAdd(fullName, type);
                }
            }
        }

        if (types.Length != 0)
        {
            type = type.MakeGenericType(types);
        }

        return type;
    }

    private static string Escape(string str)
    {
        // We escape the \ with \\, so that we can safely escape the
        // "|" (that we use as a separator) with "\|"
        str = str.Replace(@"\", @"\\");
        str = str.Replace(@"|", @"\|");
        return str;
    }
}
```

This big, fat, block of code will use `Reflection.Emit` to generate at runtime some classes with the properties named however you want (you can even use characters that are illegal in C#). These classes will follow the naming conventions of the anonymous classes generated by the C# compiler 12.0.31101.0 . They should be nearly equal even at the IL level. All the various `Equals()`, `GetHashCode()` and `ToString()` are implemented as implemented by the C# compiler 12.0.31101.0, all the fields have the same name, the `CompilerGeneratedAttribute` is inserted (this is morally wrong, I know :-) ) and so on. So the classes generated [walk like an anonymous duck](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_test) and quack like an anonymous duck... They are pratically anonymous ducks :-) (note that Roslyn ducks are of a different sub specie... Their plumage is a little different... an anonymous duck connaisseur could easily distinguish the two sub species :-) )

Now, if you want to ask [cui prodest?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cui_bono) The generated classes can only be used through reflection, so they are difficult to use, but they have a specific use-case, that Marc Gravell individuated: there are parts of the .NET framework that heavily use reflection to render objects (for example all the various datagrids). These parts are incompatible with `dynamic` objects and often don't support `object[]`. A solution is often to encapsulate the data in a `DataTable`... or you can use this :-)

In your specific case, you can use this method:

```
public static object FromDictToAnonymousObj<TValue>(IDictionary<string, TValue> dict)
{
    var types = new Type[dict.Count];

    for (int i = 0; i < types.Length; i++)
    {
        types[i] = typeof(TValue);
    }

    // dictionaries don't have an order, so we force an order based
    // on the Key
    var ordered = dict.OrderBy(x => x.Key).ToArray();

    string[] names = Array.ConvertAll(ordered, x => x.Key);

    Type type = AnonymousType.CreateType(types, names);

    object[] values = Array.ConvertAll(ordered, x => (object)x.Value);

    object obj = type.GetConstructor(types).Invoke(values);

    return obj;
}
```

like this:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    {"Id", "1"},
    {"Title", "My title"},
    {"Description", "Blah blah blah"},
};

object obj1 = FromDictToAnonymousObj(dict);
```

to obtain your object.

Comment: An updated version can be found at https://github.com/StefH/System.Linq.Dynamic.Core/blob/master/src/System.Linq.Dynamic.Core/DynamicClassFactory.cs

Comment: Nice, but I made a more limited version, but I wish it merged matching types like the compiler.

Comment: @NetMage That is a question... It isn't very much difficult (you only need to extract the "signature" of your type in some way and use it as the key in a dictionary), but stil it requires various lines of code

Answer (score 4):

Basically, that isn't something that you can do trivially; anonymous types still have all the usual code behind the scenes: just you don't see it. What you *can* do is the same thing via `dynamic`, but that won't work for APIs that expect reflection etc - so given that you'd have to be accessing by key, for most code dictionary access will be more convenient than an anonymous type or `dynamic` type.

Answer (score 3):

Here's how you could do it as an `ExpandoObject` (help from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4938442/526704))

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    {"Id", "1"},
    {"Title", "My title"},
    {"Description", "Blah blah blah"},
};

var expando = new ExpandoObject()  as IDictionary<string, Object>;
foreach(var kvp in dict)
    expando.Add(kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
```

Answer (score 3):

It isn't an anonymous object but you can accomplish this with a [DynamicObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.dynamicobject%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)! You could do the following.

```
public class MyExpando : DynamicObject
{
    Dictionary<string, object> dictionary;
    public MyExpando()
    {
       dictionary = new Dictionary<string, object>
       {
            {"Id", "1"},
            {"Title", "My title"},
            {"Description", "Blah blah blah"},
       };
    }

    public override bool TryGetMember(GetMemberBinder binder, out object result)
    {
        return dictionary.TryGetValue(binder.Name, out result);
    }

    public override bool TrySetMember(SetMemberBinder binder, object value)
    {
        if (!dictionary.ContainsKey(binder.Name))
            return false;
        dictionary[binder.Name] = value;
        return true;
    }
}
```

Then you have your object with the properties you want.

```
dynamic o = new MyExpando();
Console.WriteLine("Id :  " + o.Id + ", Title : " + o.Title + ", Description : " + o.Description);
```

Downside of course is there is no type checking at compile time and no check to see if the member exists either at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

I need it to be able to use enum values in javascript side
By using Eval, I have reached a level that will at least work. Maybe it will help you...
The [url link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53844/how-can-i-evaluate-a-c-sharp-expression-dynamically) where I adapted the Eval related codes

```
public enum ServerTypes { none = 0, uni = 1, home = 2, app = 3 }
public static object ToClass(Type value)
    {
        if (value.IsEnum)
        {
            var info = String.Concat("new {", String.Join(", ", Enum.GetNames(value).Select((x, i) => String.Join(" = ", x, Enum.GetValues(value).GetValue(i).ToInt32().ToString()))), "}");
            var nmspc = typeof(Tools).Namespace;
            var cp = new CompilerParameters();
            cp.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("system.dll");
            cp.CompilerOptions = "/t:library";
            cp.GenerateInMemory = true;
            var sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.AppendLine(String.Concat("namespace ", nmspc, " { using System; public class CSCodeEvaler { public object EvalCode() { "));
            sb.AppendLine(String.Format("return {0};", info));
            sb.AppendLine(" } } }");
            var cr = new CSharpCodeProvider().CompileAssemblyFromSource(cp, sb.ToString());
            if (cr.Errors.Count > 0) { throw new InvalidExpressionException(String.Format("Error ({0}) evaluating: {1}", cr.Errors[0].ErrorText, info)); }
            else
            {
                var o = cr.CompiledAssembly.CreateInstance(String.Concat(nmspc, ".CSCodeEvaler"));
                return o.GetType().GetMethod("EvalCode").Invoke(o, null);
            }
        }
        else { throw new NotImplementedException("value tipi enum olmalıdır!"); }
    }
```

And finally result

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do this, but you have to "describe" the anonymous object. Since you cannot its type as a generic, you have to create an instance and let the generic type be inferred.

```cs
using System.Reflection;

static T ToAnonymousObject<T>(Dictionary<string, object> source, T _)
{
    PropertyInfo[] properties = typeof(T).GetProps();
    // This array is used to search T for a suitable constructor.
    // Anonymous objects are immutable, but it seems like they always have a constructor like this available
    Type[] propertyTypes = new Type[properties.Length];
    // this array is passed to the constructor
    object[] values = new object[properties.Length];

    for (int i = 0; i < properties.Length; i++) 
    {
        types[i] = properties[i].PropertyType;
        values[i] = source[properties[i].Name];
    }

    // find the constructor that takes values for all properties as arguments
    // seems like this always exists for anonymous types
    ConstructorInfo? constructor = typeof(T).GetConstructor(types);

    if (constructor is null)
        throw new Exception($"Type '{typeof(T)}' does not contain a suitable constructor");

    T @new = (T)constructor.Invoke(values);
    return @new;
}

// usage

// source dictionary
Dictionary<string, object> myDictionary = new () 
{   
    { "myInt", 3 }, 
    { "myString", "string value" }, 
    { "ignoredKeyBecauseItIsNotSpecifiedInTheAnonymousObject", true }
};

// Create an instance of the target anonymous type, so we can "describe" the shape
var targetType = new { myInt = default(int), myString = default(string) };

var myAnonymousObject = ToAnonymousObject(myDictionary, targetType);

// myAnonymousObject is strongly typed, just as targetType was defined
Console.WriteLine(myAnonymousObject.myInt); // 3
```

[Using anonymous type as generic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1409776)