# Methods for dynamically creating an array in C#

Tags: c#, .net, scripting

First, I don't have much experience in .Net - especially within the last 7 years.

I'm trying to develop an application and would to incorporate another library (https://github.com/Giorgi/Math-Expression-Evaluator)

That library allows me to evaluate math expressions like `Evaluate("a+b", a: 1,b: 1)`.  The method signature is `public decimal Evaluate(string expression, object argument = null)`

1. I would like to understand better how .Net translates comma-separated arguments into a single "argument".
2. I'm not sure how to create that argument dynamically.. for example, iterating through a list of values and creating an object that will match the appropriate argument for that signature.

I'm really just looking for pointers for documentation and more information.. Thanks for anything.

EDIT:  Sorry.. purposely left it broad because I wasn't looking for people to do my work for me.. just can't seem to find a starting point to do my own research.

The method is called like

```
dynamic engine = new ExpressionEvaluator() ; 
engine.Evaluate("(c+b)*a", a: 6, b: 4.5, c: 2.6)) ;
```

In the body of Evalute() is this code (which turns that argument into a Dictionary of String, Decimal pairs.

```
if (argument == null)
        {
            return new Dictionary<string, decimal>();
        }

        var argumentType = argument.GetType();

        var properties = argumentType.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public)
            .Where(p => p.CanRead && IsNumeric(p.PropertyType));

        var arguments = properties.ToDictionary(property => property.Name,
            property => Convert.ToDecimal(property.GetValue(argument, null)));

        return arguments;
```

What I'd like to be able to do is parse a String like "a:1,b:2" and turn it into an object that matches that `Evaluate()` signature.

Comment: Even question 1 is by far too broad and contains many steps. Not to mentioned question 2. "Understand better" imples that you already understand "something". So what do you understand and what don´t you?

Comment: It is quite interesting... is the the `new { ... }` implicit in point 1?

Comment: I'm not sure what question #1 even *means*.  Translating comma-separated arguments into a single argument?

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding something in C# myself, I don't see how the example use of `Evaluate()` matches that method signature at all.

Comment: Point 1 would be down the the language (C#) specs and the compiler, not .Net as that is just a framework

Comment: Ah no... The class is dynamic and is handling in a dynamic way the use of the method... fascinating

Comment: Taking a look at the library, it looks like the `Evaluate` method is overloaded as well, so the example you posted is most likely invoking the method with the signature `private decimal Evaluate(string expression, Dictionary<string, decimal> arguments)`.

Comment: No no... The first step is [`public override bool TryInvokeMember(InvokeMemberBinder binder, object[] args, out object result)`](https://github.com/Giorgi/Math-Expression-Evaluator/blob/abc2287f419212b81b39ded8d863debbfed89a58/SimpleExpressionEvaluator/ExpressionEvaluator.cs#L81)... Wow!

Comment: The link you give is a link to the source code, why not read it and find out how it works?

Comment: @Neil Because I too don't know exactly how it works and I'm quite good with C#? This is probably the first example I've ever seen of subclassing `DynamicObject` just to do that trick.

Comment: Can't decide if this library is evil, genius or evil genius...

Comment: @xanatos It's open now, you can post. Maybe worth mentioning that `engine` also needs to be declared as `dynamic`

Comment: This question shouldn't be closed, specially with the edit. The OP is clearly asking how the compiler is able to resolve overloads that are seemingly not declared in the linked code... Xanatos has answered how in comments.

Comment: @Neil I did read the code.. and I basically understand what it's doing.  I just don't know how to create an object that would match the signature.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That library is using high level magic... Very high level :-)

The trick is that the class is declared as:

```
public class ExpressionEvaluator : DynamicObject
```

So it is a class that implements the `dynamic` magic introduced in .NET 4.0

Now... In the class there are two `Evaluate` methods:

```
public decimal Evaluate(string expression, object argument = null)
```

and

```
private decimal Evaluate(string expression, Dictionary<string, decimal> arguments)
```

The only method normally visible and usable is the first one. It is used like:

```
engine.Evaluate("a + b + c", new { a = 1, b = 2, c = 3 });
```

The `new { ... }` creates an anonymous object, that is then "unpacked" [here](https://github.com/Giorgi/Math-Expression-Evaluator/blob/abc2287f419212b81b39ded8d863debbfed89a58/SimpleExpressionEvaluator/ExpressionEvaluator.cs#L69) through the use of reflection to a `Dictionary<string, decimal>` to be fed to the `private Evaluate()`.

If you try to use the other notation, the one like:

```
engine.Evaluate("a + b + c", a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 });
```

then the .NET can't match the method to the `public Evaluate()` that is present, but the class, being a subclass of `DynamicObject`, causes the C# compiler to write some "magic" code that launches [this](https://github.com/Giorgi/Math-Expression-Evaluator/blob/abc2287f419212b81b39ded8d863debbfed89a58/SimpleExpressionEvaluator/ExpressionEvaluator.cs#L81) method (that is still implemented by the ExpressionEvaluator):

```
public override bool TryInvokeMember(InvokeMemberBinder binder, object[] args, out object result)
```

That first checks that we want to call Evaluate:

```
if (nameof(Evaluate) != binder.Name)
```

and if we are trying to call Evaluate, it unpacks the parameters to a `new Dictionary<string, decimal>()` and then calls the `private Evaluate()`.

As a sidenote, to use the "dynamic" way of writing `Evaluate` you have to declare the `engine` variable like;

```
dynamic dynamicEngine = new ExpressionEvaluator();
```

So using the `dynamic` variable type.

Now... As the library is written you can:

- Use an anonymous object, with the problem that anonymous objects must have their "shape" defined at compile time (so at compile time you must know that you will need a `a`, a `b` and a `c`. You can't need a `d` at runtime if you didn't create a `new { a, b, c, d }` at compile time). See for example a [response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29428640/613130) I gave three years ago about how to create dynamic anonymous types at runtime. One of the reasons I gave for that block of code was:

  > there are parts of the .NET framework that heavily use reflection to render objects (for example all the various datagrids). These parts are incompatible with dynamic objects and often don't support object[]. A solution is often to encapsulate the data in a DataTable... or you can use this :-)

  Note that in one of the comments to that response there is a link to a modified version of my code used by one of the many implementations of Dynamic.Linq.
- Use a non-anonymous object (a `new Foo { a = 1, b = 2 c = 3 }`). The library doesn't make distinctions between anonymous and non-anonymous objects. So same limitation as before, because at compile time you need a `Foo` class with the right number of parameters
- Use the `dynamic` notation. Sadly even that is quite static. You can't easily add new parameters, that for the number and name of the "variables" must be defined at compile time.

A possible solution is to modify the source code (it is a single file) and make `public` this method:

```
private decimal Evaluate(string expression, Dictionary<string, decimal> arguments)
```

then you can easily and dynamically populate the `Dictionary<string, decimal> arguments`

Comment: So I believe (to use the same signature), I would have to dynamically create one of these `new { a = 1, b = 2, c = 3 }`  Not sure how to do that, but it's a starting point.  Thanks

Comment: @Greg Yes. But note that the number and name of the variables would be fixed. Sadly the libary doesn't exposes the `private Evaluate` that uses the `Dictionary<>` method. That would be very easy to truly dynamically use.

Comment: I agree, and I have cloned his library and will submit a pull request.  But I wanted to make sure that there wasn't a way of using the signature as is before I started asking for additional features.  Thanks again.

Comment: @Greg I feel the simplest way is to change from `private` to `public` and use that method. Because creating anonymous objects at runtime is quite complex.