# How can i combine anonymous types with LINQ to JSON?

Tags: c#, json, linq, json.net, linq-to-json

consider the following json file

```
{
  "test": {
    "CR": {
     "name": "Car"
    },
    "BK": {
     "name": "Bike"
    }
}
```

How can i combine usage of anonymous types with LINQ to JSON for creating key-value pairs of

```
    CR Car
    BK Bike
```

by using LINQ to JSON?

I have tried something as simple as the following for start, but it does not even compile

```
    JObject o = JObject.Parse(s);
    var pairs = o["test"].Select(x => x.Value).ToList();
```

To be more precise something like this pseudocode

```
var pairs = o["test"].Select( new { key = x => x.firstOrDefault().Name, value = x => x.Value}).ToList();
```

Comment: You should access `test` properties by name or cast to `JProperty`

Comment: @OlivierRogier I don't see how showing how to work with JSON can answer this "create anonymous types at runtime" question... Unless OP clarifies what they *actualy* want to achieve.

Comment: @OrElse are you familiar with lambda expressions? I suggest you to look at basics of it first and make your code compile

Comment: @OlivierRogier May i ask why you closed the question?

Comment: @OrElseq because it looks like one of the suggested duplicates is what you are asking. Indeed you are welcome to [edit] question to clarify why neither apply to your case.

Comment: You can always just use LINQ to JSON to create a new `JObject` based on the original one, i.e. `var pairs = new JObject( ((JObject)o["test"]).Properties().Select(p => new JProperty(p.Name, p.Value["name"])) );`.  Or if you would prefer a dictionary then `var dictionary = ((JObject)o["test"]).Properties().ToDictionary(p => p.Name, p => (string)p.Value["name"]);`.  See: https://dotnetfiddle.net/5fnn5E

Comment: If you **must** have a runtime-created anonymous type, see [C# anonymous object with properties from dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29428640/3744182).  It's nontrivial though.

Comment: @dbc do you mind posting this as an answer? This is what i was looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than creating a runtime anonymous type with variable property names, you could use [LINQ to JSON](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/LINQtoJSON.htm) to create a restructured `JObject` like so:

```
var pairs = new JObject( ((JObject)o["test"])
                        .Properties()
                        .Select(p => new JProperty(p.Name, p.Value["name"])) );
```

Or, if you would prefer a `Dictionary<string, string>`, you may do:

```
var dictionary = ((JObject)o["test"]).Properties()
    .ToDictionary(p => p.Name, p => (string)p.Value["name"]);
```

Or an `ExpandoObject`:

```
var expando = new ExpandoObject();
foreach (var p in ((JObject)o["test"]).Properties())
{
    IDictionary<string, object> d = expando;
    d.Add(p.Name, (string)p.Value["name"]);
}
```

Creating a run-time anonymous type using property names defined by a dictionary is nontrivial as it requires runtime code generation.  If you really need this, see *[C# anonymous object with properties from dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29413942/3744182)*.

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/5fnn5E).